# why pdf printing with cups is slow on raspberry pi, like starts after 30 seconds

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, cups

I have a raspberry pi with Raspbian. when I print I see it finished sending the print already. but it starts printing only like 30 seconds later.
I have a USB connected hp printer, but it is also similarly slow with cups-pdf virtual printer.

how to make it print fast?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

printing was slow in raspberry because raspberry pi has a slow CPU.
GhostScript pdf to ps conversion took a long time and a large amount of CPU.

to solve this 
first I turned on debugging logging and saw it received a print job and executed conversion and then there is a pause. like seconds skip. then in a console, I executed sudo htop (a modern list of processes program) and filtered by cups, and saw, it was running on a one CPU out of 4, at 100% for like 20 seconds. gs. and then ps2pdf when using the virtual pdf printer cups-pdf.
so I created a PostScript document at first instead of pdf and it printed fast.

so it means cups expects postscript not pdf.

Comment: It is possible to improve processing speed by using poppler (`pdftops`) filter instead of ghostscript.  

https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-filters#postscript-printing-renderer-and-resolution-selection  


    The selection is done by the "pdftops-renderer" option, setting it to "gs", "pdftops", "pdftocairo", "acroread", "mupdf", or "hybrid":

    Per-job:
    lpr -o pdftops-renderer=pdftops ...
    Per-queue default:
    lpadmin -p printer -o pdftops-renderer-default=gs
    Remove default:
    lpadmin -p printer -R pdftops-renderer-default